# Passing an argument to remote command in Powershell

Tags: powershell, remote-access

Using Powershell I want to create a directory on a remote computer with the current time stamp in its name. After setting up remoting and the variables that I need, this is easy to achieve for me, e.g.:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {New-Item -ItemType Directory c:\tmp\$(get-date -f yyyyMMddhhmmss)}
```

Now I would like to retrieve the date on the local machine like

```
$currentDateTime = get-date -f yyyyMMddhhmmss
```

and then use that variable to create and, later on, refer to such a directory remotely, e.g. for copying files into it, like:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {New-Item -ItemType Directory c:\tmp\$currentDateTime}
....(20 secs later)....
copy file \\$server\C$\tmp\$currentDateTime
```

The first line does not work since the variable does not seem to be known in the script context, so I also don't know whether the second line would work if I get the first one done.

As an alternative, I would also be happy (actually: prefer) to create the directory from the local machine as follows

```
New-Item -Path \\$server\C$\tmp\$currentDateTime
```

This seems to fail cause of missing credentials, but the `-Credential` switch does not seem to be supported for this command (?).

How do you create such a folder on the remote machine? (I need to do this with version 2.0 of Powershell)

Comment: On my Server with powershell V2.0 I have the -Credential switch at New-Item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell don't know the variabel in the invoke command. With the `-ArgumentList` you can pass it into the invoke command. 
Look at the example, do this work for you?

```
$datCurrentDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddhhmmss"
$strFolderPath = "\\servername\c$\temp\$($datCurrentDate)_Foldername"

$scbScriptBlock = {
    $strFolderPath = $args[0]    
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $strFolderPath 
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -credential $Cred -ScriptBlock $scbScriptBlock -ArgumentList $strFolderPath
....(20 secs later)....
copy file $strFolderPath
```